How table changes are automatically reflecting in table on another server?
I checked a couple of posts which advise a trigger but in my scenario I could not find any trigger.
I have a server DB. The client DB has Linked Server setup and points to server DB.
Any value change in a master table of Server DB is automatically getting updated in client DB  master table.
I checked and there are no table-level or db-level triggers.
How the changes are getting automatically updated in the client DB table ?

Transaction replication?

There are few master tables. Any column value change is automatically reflecting in real-time in the client table.

@JamesZ How to check where Transactional Replication is setup and what all tables are included in it ?

There are no completely real-time systems (that i know of) unless there are some triggers, even tran replication is delayed a bit. are you sure the client table is a table, and not a view against the linked server? If you do an update under a show plan, do you see any code that is triggered beside the update itself

@siggemannen Yes it is a table. I changed a numeric value in the server table and then refreshed the query in the child table. It is reflecting immediately. I checked Triggers in client and server tables. There are no triggers.

Ok, did you do the "query plan" thing?

@siggemannen No. How to do the query plan ? On server or client db ?

You can see replication things under "Replication" in management studio. There should be either local publisher or local subscription depending on which side you look at. Not sure if any user special rights are needed though.

if you're running script in sql server management studio, there's a button for "include actual query plan" Also, how do you know that the client table is a table? A lot of people would love to have real time replication in sql server, so i'm a bit sceptical. Although, it could be some code is polling the server changes and then performing a replication manually.

@JamesZ As of now, I can see no Local Publications or Local Subscriptions on the server DB

@siggemannen I can connect to the client DB and under Tables the table is appearing where the change is happening.

Does select * from sys.change_tracking_tables on the server returns any rows? And what does exec sys.sp_cdc_help_jobs returns on the server

@siggemannen The SELECT statement did not return any row. The other EXEC statement I executed on the UAT Server DB, it shows: "Change Tracking not enabled"

A linked server setup in MS SQL Server is a link to access databases on the other server 'as if' they are local databases.  This isn't a replication or log-shipping scenario,  it's simply giving you access to the server on the master database.
The changes aren't 'being reflected in a table on the client server'  but instead the client server is connecting directly to the master table, therefore showing you the updates in real-time.

You mean, a change in the master table of server will also show-up in client db table in real time ? What about other non-master tables on the client ? It is not happening there only with the few master tables.
